# Creating links to current controller in a Partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a partial view that renders a paging control that is reused across several views and actions. But I can't work out how to generate a URL for my current action just appending a page number without knowing the action and controller I came from in the partial view.

Can you get this information in a partial view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fetch the current controller and action from the route data:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "link text",
    ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action"),
    ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller"),
    new { page = "123" },
    null
) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass that information into the into the `ViewData` for the paging control. Look at the overloads for `RenderPartial` to pass additional view data.